# problems with dice game

Tags: java, netbeans

whenever the code goes through the compiler it prints out the same number an infinite amount of times, i need it to compile random numbers several times. I tried to use the while loop to print out more times. However it just prints out the same number. The purpose of the game is for two players (and AI and one person), to compete to first reach 100 points, whenever a player gets two 1's the points will reset.

```
class piggame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dice d1 = new Dice();
        d1.rolls();
        int dave = d1.rolls();

        Dice d2 = new Dice();
        d2.rolls();
        int joe = d2.rolls();

        Dice d3 = new Dice();
        d3.rolls();
        int kurt = d1.rolls() + d2.rolls();

        int sum1 = d1.rolls() + d2.rolls(); 
        sum1 += d1.rolls() + d2.rolls();


        while (dave != 1 && joe != 1){        
            System.out.println("you have rolled " + kurt);
        }   
    }      
} 

class Dice {

    public int rolls() {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt(6) +1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you only roll the dice **before** your loop starts. Then they are having the same value for the whole time while the loop runs.

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: Re-roll the dices inside the loop .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `rolls()` inside loop. At snippet you pasted rolls are made once before the loop and then inside it you just printing this one roll result (which indeed will be infinite loop OR won't execute in case of rolls being ones right away, as rolls are never made again when you inside this `while`).

Answer (score 1):

This code is not perfect, but it should solve your problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int dave = 0;
 int joe = 0;
 int kurt = 0;
 while (dave != 1 && joe != 1){
   Dice d1 = new Dice();
   d1.rolls();
   dave = d1.rolls();

   Dice d2 = new Dice();
   d2.rolls();
   joe = d2.rolls();

   Dice d3 = new Dice();
   d3.rolls();
   kurt = d1.rolls() + d2.rolls();

   int sum1 = d1.rolls() + d2.rolls(); 
   sum1 += d1.rolls() + d2.rolls();
   System.out.println("you have rolled " + kurt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

class PigGame 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    int dave = 0;
    int joe = 0;
    int kurt = 0;
    int roll_count = 0;

    while (dave != 1 && joe != 1)
    {
      System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println("Roll number: " + roll_count++);
      System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");

      dave = new Dice().roll();
      joe  = new Dice().roll();
      kurt = new Dice().roll();

      System.out.println("Dave rolled: " + dave);
      System.out.println("Joe rolled: " + joe);
      System.out.println("Kurt rolled: " + kurt);
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }   
} 


class Dice {
  public int roll() { return new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're providing a solution to the given requirement:

1. Two players (but you have included three players - Joe, Dave and Kurt).
2. If a player rolls two consecutive ones, that player's score is reset (e.g. if player Dave rolls a one and then rolls another one on his next turn, his score is reset to 0).

In my previous answer, I was only trying to tidy up your code. I wasn't looking at the actual requirement.

You haven't mentioned if a player gets a single point per roll of the dice, or if the value of what they roll is added to their score. I'm going to assume it's the latter.

You should include another class called "Player". The Player class would contain variables to store what the current roll was, what the previous roll was, and the player's current score. It should also include methods to roll the dice, check if the player has reached a score of 100, check if a player has rolled two consecutive ones.

Here's a very simple implementation (that will tell you which player wins at the end, and how many points the winner has won by):

```
import java.util.Random;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
class PigGame 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Player player1 = new Player("Dave");
    Player player2 = new Player("Joe");
    int roll_count = 0;

    while (!player1.reachedFinishingScore() && !player2.reachedFinishingScore())
    {
      int p1_roll = player1.roll();
      int p2_roll = player2.roll();

      System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println("Roll number: " + roll_count++);
      System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println(player1.get_name() + " rolled: " + p1_roll + ". Total Score: " + player1.get_score());
      System.out.println(player2.get_name() + " rolled: " + p2_roll + ". Total Score: " + player2.get_score());
      System.out.println("");
    }

    if (player1.get_score() == player2.get_score()) 
      System.out.println("It was a draw!");
    else if (player1.get_score() > player2.get_score()) 
      System.out.println(player1.get_name() + " wins by " + (player1.get_score() - player2.get_score()) + " points!");
    else 
      System.out.println(player2.get_name() + " wins by " + (player2.get_score() - player1.get_score()) + " points!");

    System.out.println("");
  }
} 

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Dice {
  public int roll() { return new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;   }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Player
{
  private String name; // Player's name.
  private int prev_roll = 0; // Value of Player's previous roll.
  private int curr_roll = 0; // Value of Player's current roll.
  private int score = 0;     // The Player's score.

  public Player(String name) { this.name = name; }

  public int roll()
  {
    int curr_roll = new Dice().roll();
    this.prev_roll = this.curr_roll; // Make previous roll value of last current roll.
    this.curr_roll = curr_roll;      // Set value of current roll to what was just rolled.
    this.score += curr_roll;
    if (rolledTwoOnes()) this.score = 0;

    return curr_roll;
  }

  private boolean rolledTwoOnes() { return (this.prev_roll == 1 && this.curr_roll == 1); }
  public boolean reachedFinishingScore() { return this.score >= 100; }
  public int get_score() { return score; }
  public String get_name() { return this.name; }
}
```

The above implementation could be improved by not "hard-coding" player1 and player2. Instead, you could use an array of players, which would make it easier to not limit the number of players (i.e. you could have 100 players).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, last one (I promise):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Config
{
  public static final int NUM_OF_PLAYERS = 10;
  public static final int NUM_OF_DICE_FACES = 6;
  public static final int WINNING_SCORE = 100;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
class PigGame 
{
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------      
  public static void create_players(Player[] p, int num_players)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++)
      p[i] = new Player("Player " + String.format("%02d", i + 1));
  }


  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------      
  public static void all_players_roll_dice(Player[] p)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
      p[i].roll();
  }

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  public static boolean no_winners(Player[] p)
  {
    int i = 0;
    boolean bWinner = false;
    while (i < p.length && (bWinner = !p[i].reachedFinishingScore()))
      i++;

    return bWinner;
  }

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  public static void display_roll_details(Player[] p, int current_roll)
  {
    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("CURRENT ROLL: " + (current_roll + 1));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
      System.out.println(p[i].get_name() + " rolled: " + p[i].get_roll() + 
        ". Score: " + p[i].get_score());
  }

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------    
  public static void display_final_scores(Player[] p, int roll_count)
  {
    System.out.println("\n\n**********************************************************");
    System.out.println("FINAL SCORES AFTER " + roll_count + " ROLLS (HIGHEST TO LOWEST):");
    System.out.println("**********************************************************\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
    {
      Arrays.sort(p);
      System.out.println(p[i].get_name() + " scored: " + p[i].get_score());
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nDon't be a player hater!\n\n");
  }

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Player[] players = new Player[Config.NUM_OF_PLAYERS];

    create_players(players, Config.NUM_OF_PLAYERS);

    int roll_count = 0;
    while (no_winners(players))
    {
      all_players_roll_dice(players);
      display_roll_details(players, roll_count++);
    }

    display_final_scores(players, roll_count);

  }
} 

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Dice {
  public int roll() { return new Random().nextInt(Config.NUM_OF_DICE_FACES) + 1;    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Player implements Comparable<Player>
{
  private String name; // Player's name.
  private int prev_roll = 0; // Value of Player's previous roll.
  private int curr_roll = 0; // Value of Player's current roll.
  private int score = 0;     // The Player's score.

  public Player(String name) { this.name = name; }

  public int roll()
  {
    int curr_roll = new Dice().roll();
    this.prev_roll = this.curr_roll; // Make previous roll value of last current roll.
    this.curr_roll = curr_roll;      // Set value of current roll to what was just rolled.
    this.score += curr_roll;
    if (rolledTwoOnes()) this.score = 0;

    return curr_roll;
  }

  private boolean rolledTwoOnes() { return (this.prev_roll == 1 && this.curr_roll == 1); }
  public boolean reachedFinishingScore() { return this.score >= Config.WINNING_SCORE; }
  public int get_score() { return this.score; }
  public int get_roll() { return this.curr_roll; }
  public String get_name() { return this.name; }

  // For sorting the array (from highest scores to lowest).
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Player p) 
  { 
    return ((Integer)p.get_score()).compareTo(((Integer)get_score())); 
  }
}
```

Using the above, you can easily alter the number of players, number of dice faces, and the score that needs to be reached for a win.